# I want to know the capital of a country only introducing a country

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, location, country

I would like to find a way to find the capital city of a country, and in such a way that if the country changes, the capital would  do so, i want my program would print that.  (Python 3.x)

Answer (score 1):

I used from `countryinfo` package from https://github.com/porimol/countryinfo. You can install it by `pip install countryinfo`.

Once installed, you can use the below code to generate different countries. Change the country name to any other country.

```
from countryinfo import CountryInfo


country = CountryInfo('INDIA')
print(country.capital())
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me this error: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I hope the issue is with encoding, can you check if you set utf-8 in the environment. If you are using Python 2 try the below one. 
 ``` 
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```
Put the line at the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

my method might seem to be complicated but I'd like to utilize [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) for such queries

`wikipedia` library: `pip install wikipedia`

wikipedia docs: https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api

```
import wikipedia

countries = ['Ukraine', 'Belgium', 'Italy']

for country in countries:
    print(wikipedia.page(f'capital of {country}').title)
```